# Django reverse proxy server CORS

Tags: python, django, proxy, cors, cors-anywhere

I am looking to write a route that works exactly like this https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere in django

I'm thinking it's similar like in this question [Django as reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226173/django-as-reverse-proxy)

My question is how to add cors headers into it. I've also take a look of this https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers, will the reverse proxy simply works for CORS, just by adding the django-cors-headers?

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623792/django-cors-headers-not-working/35625221#35625221 seems relevant. That suggests using Django HTTP Proxy. To make that CORS-enabled I guess you would need to add https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers as you’ve mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in [Django-cors-headers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623792/django-cors-headers-not-working/35625221#35625221) does the trick, if you want an image simply change the content type in the response to match the image,